# MS SQL recursively get child id with parent ids

Tags: sql, full-text-search, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have created a search SQL query, I'm almost finished I only need to match the WHERE clause with an id and it's parent ids. Currently I only match with an id and not it's parents. I'm not sure how to solve this.

This is my query, the code where I need the change is where the comment "This part needs to match the tileid and it's parent tileids" is. Based on the [TileId] I need to get the [TileId] and it's parents.

```html
WITH [TileSearch_CTE] ([TileId], [TypeId], [TypeName], [Title], [Info]) AS 
( 
 SELECT TOP 10 [TileId], [TypeId], [TypeName], [Title], [Info] 
 FROM [Priox].[TileFullTextSearchNL] 
 INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([Priox].[TileFullTextSearchNL], *, '"searchText*"') AS [CT] 
 ON [Priox].[TileFullTextSearchNL].[TileId] = [CT].[Key] 
 WHERE 
 (
  NOT EXISTS 
  (
   SELECT [intPortalTileFilterId] 
   FROM [Priox].[tblPortalTileFilter] 
   WHERE [intPortalTileIdFk] = [TileId] -- This part needs to match the tileid and it's parent tileids
  ) 
  OR EXISTS 
  (
   SELECT [intPortalTileFilterId] 
   FROM [Priox].[tblPortalTileFilter] 
   WHERE [intPortalTileIdFk] = [TileId] -- This part needs to match the tileid and it's parent tileids
   AND [intPortalFilterIdFk] IN (56) 
  )
 ) 
 ORDER BY [CT].[Rank] DESC 
) 
SELECT [TileId], [TypeName], [Title], [Info], [TP].[strName] AS [ParamName], [TPV].[strParamValue] AS [ParamValue] 
FROM [TileSearch_CTE] 
LEFT JOIN [Priox].[tblPortalTileParam] AS [TP] ON [TP].[intTileType] = [TileSearch_CTE].[TypeId] 
LEFT JOIN [Priox].[tblPortalTileParamValue] AS [TPV] ON [TPV].[intTileParamIdFk] = [TP].[intPortalTileParamId] AND [TileSearch_CTE].[TileId] = [TPV].[intTileIdFk]
```

This is the database structure of the tiles.

[image]

So the query should do something like this.

```html
SELECT [intPortalTileFilterId] 
FROM [Priox].[tblPortalTileFilter] 
WHERE [intPortalTileIdFk] IN (438,1317)
```

I fixed it myself, created a function that returns the parents and the child.

```html
CREATE FUNCTION [Priox].[GetTileIdHierarchy]
(
    @tileId int    
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN  
(
 WITH parents AS
    (
  SELECT [intPortalTileId], [intPortalTileId] AS [intParentIdFk]
  FROM [Priox].[tblPortalTile] WHERE [intPortalTileId] = @tileId
     UNION ALL
     SELECT p.[intPortalTileId], [Priox].[tblPortalTile].[intParentIdFk] 
  FROM parents p
  INNER JOIN [Priox].[tblPortalTile] on p.[intParentIdFk] = [Priox].[tblPortalTile].[intPortalTileId]
        AND [Priox].[tblPortalTile].[intParentIdFk] IS NOT NULL
  AND [Priox].[tblPortalTile].[intPortalTileId] <> [Priox].[tblPortalTile].[intParentIdFk]
 )  
 SELECT [intPortalTileId], [intParentIdFk]
    FROM parents
 WHERE [intPortalTileId] = @tileId 
)
GO
```

And changed my search query accordingly.

```html
WITH [TileSearch_CTE] ([TileId], [TypeId], [TypeName], [Title], [Info], [Rank]) AS 
( 
 SELECT TOP 10 [TileId], [TypeId], [TypeName], [Title], [Info],[CT].[Rank] AS [Rank]
 FROM [Priox].[TileFullTextSearchNL] 
 INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([Priox].[TileFullTextSearchNL], *, '"searchTerm*"') AS [CT]
 ON [Priox].[TileFullTextSearchNL].[TileId] = [CT].[Key] 
 WHERE 
 (
  NOT EXISTS 
  (
   SELECT [intPortalTileFilterId] 
   FROM [Priox].[tblPortalTileFilter]    
   WHERE [intPortalTileIdFk] IN  
   (
    SELECT [intParentIdFk] FROM [Priox].[GetTileIdHierarchy] ([TileId])
   )   
  ) 
  OR 
  EXISTS 
  (
   SELECT [intPortalTileFilterId] 
   FROM [Priox].[tblPortalTileFilter]    
   WHERE [intPortalTileIdFk] IN  
   (
    SELECT [intParentIdFk] FROM [Priox].[GetTileIdHierarchy] ([TileId])    
   )      
   AND [intPortalFilterIdFk] IN (51)    
  )
 ) 
 ORDER BY [CT].[Rank] DESC 
) 
SELECT [TileId], [TypeName], [Title], [Info], [TP].[strName] AS [ParamName], [TPV].[strParamValue] AS [ParamValue] , [Rank]
FROM [TileSearch_CTE] 
LEFT JOIN [Priox].[tblPortalTileParam] AS [TP] ON [TP].[intTileType] = [TileSearch_CTE].[TypeId] 
LEFT JOIN [Priox].[tblPortalTileParamValue] AS [TPV] ON [TPV].[intTileParamIdFk] = [TP].[intPortalTileParamId] AND [TileSearch_CTE].[TileId] = [TPV].[intTileIdFk]
```

Comment: Can a hierarchy ever have more two members? (i.e. can there be grandchildren?)

Comment: Yes it can have an infinite amount of grandchildren, In my example I only show a child and a parent

Answer (score 0):

I edited the starting post with the solution.